# Croesus' Pizzas

Tags: geometry, enigmatic-puzzle

This scrap of paper caught my eye, partially trodden in to a mush outside Bank tube station. It appears to be part of a pizza menu (illegible areas marked with square brackets):

```
         Extra Topping Price List               New for 2017!

         [  ]   [  ]    [  ]    [  ]    [  ]    [  ]    [  ]    [  ]
 12"     £1.73  £2.08   £10.65  £11.70  [  ]    [  ]    [  ]    £174
 14"     £2.35  £2.86   £15.00  £16.10  [  ]    [  ]    [  ]    £238
```

1. Which eight toppings are advertised, and how were their prices arrived at?
2. What are the missing prices?

The toppings have inherent properties that lead to their pricing, so the answer isn't *£1.73 worth of arbitrary pizza topping*

Hint

> I cross the road and head up Threadneedle Street as I puzzle over the fragment. Strange, it sort of looks like the price has been rounded up differently for each topping?

Hint

> It's only later, back at my hotel room and packing my suitcase as neatly as possible, that the penny finally drops. Yuck!

Hint

> *Dough* I laugh to myself. Thinking, "is that even a legal foodstuff?". I guess there's a market for everything.

Comment: The geometry tag is confusing me. Is it a hint?

Comment: answering the question will require geometry

Comment: Wow, that *is* an enigmatic puzzle!

Comment: Maybe a silly question, but are the pizza toppings actual pizza toppings?

Comment: I've been wondering the same thing as @ShawnHolzworth. Are we looking for things like 'salami' and 'anchovies', or things which physically exist but which you wouldn't normally find on a pizza, like 'bungalow' or 'Saturn V', or even completely abstract things (such as '10%' or 'e^i' or 'love')? (Feel free not to answer if it would spoil the puzzle).

Comment: I'll take a Saturn V on deep crust base for £238 please.

Comment: latest hint may help with that

Comment: I think I know the toppings but I can't figure out the prices. What level of geometry are we talking here? Do we need to derive the optimal [circle packing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_packing) method to cram as much topping on the pizza as possible?

Comment: yes (sorry) but you may not be dealing with circles

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Which eight toppings are advertised?

The eight most commonly used coins of the United Kingdom:  1p, 2p, 5p, 10p, 20p, 50p, £1, £2. This explains your "the penny finally drops" and "dough" hints, and the "Croesus' Pizzas" title.

> how were their prices arrived at?

By multiplying the value of the coin by the amount that can fit on the pizza, packing them together as closely as you can. For example, you can fit 104 2p coins on a 12" pizza*, so it costs 2.08. This explains your "packing my suitcase as neatly as possible" hint.

> What are the missing prices?

According to my [coin packing simulation](https://ideone.com/Yq48dr),

```
         1p     2p      5p      10p     20p     50p     £1      £2
 12"     £1.73  £2.08   £10.65  £11.70  £32.60  £45.50  £151    £174
 14"     £2.35  £2.86   £15.00  £16.10  £42.20  £63.50  £199    £238
```

In 2017, the price for the £1 pie will change, because the current round coin will be replaced with a 12-sided design. This explains the "New for 2017!" header.

---

*I suspect we're using slightly different packing strategies, because I was able to fit 109 2p coins, not 104:

[image]

If I had to make an in-story justification for this, I'd say "the chef is clumsy and sometimes a few coins fall off during baking"

Comment: I'll need to look at the packing discrepancy, but I'm sure your solution is correct. thanks for the in-story justification, very charitable :)

Comment: I'll accept the answer but if you wanted to improve it there's a few missed hints (why did I arrive at that station and head up that street?). also some of the coins aren't circles.

Comment: I guess Bank tube station and Threadneedle street are in the problem because they're near the Bank of England. I know that the 20p and 50p coins aren't circular, but devising an optimal packing strategy for beveled heptagons is a little beyond my ability, so I approximated ;-)  If only they were _six_ sided, then they would tessellate nicely...